# Class.prototype.method vs this.prototype.method

Tags: javascript, prototype

I've always seen examples of Class.prototype.method, but never instances of this.prototype.method. For example:

```
function Class() {
    this.prototype.method = function() {
        alert("is this allowed?");
    };
}
```

vs

```
function Class() {}
Class.prototype.method = function() {
    alert("traditional example");
};
```

1. Does this.prototype exist?
2. Is it the same as Class.prototype?
3. What about inheritance?

Comment: Its kind of confusing if you start modifying shared members on instances. You could access prototype through this.constructor. prototype in many cases but why would you?  Maybe this answer can explain a bit about prototype.http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 22):

1. Does this.prototype exist?

   No. But, `this.constructor.prototype` should.
2. Is it the same as Class(.constructor).prototype?

   It will generally have the same value (so long as `this.constructor === Class`), but not the same intent.
3. What about inheritance?

   Each `new Class` instance will inherit from `Class.prototype`. So, a `prototype` object is good for defining shared values accessible to all instances. Then, the constructor just has to setup state that's unique to each instance.

   But, attempting to mix the 2 and set a `prototype` property within the constructor has a few problems, including a chicken-or-egg conflict as the method won't exist until the first instance is created:

   ```
   function Class() {
       this.constructor.prototype.method = function () {};
   }

   console.log(typeof Class.prototype.method); // "undefined"

   var a = new Class();

   console.log(typeof Class.prototype.method); // "function"
   ```

   And defeats some of the benefit of having the `prototype` as the method is being recreated with each additional instance:

   ```
   var method = a.method;

   console.log(a.method === method); // true

   var b = new Class();

   console.log(a.method === method); // false
   ```

Comment: in what case `this.prototype`  will exist?

Comment: @Pilot When `this` is an `instanceof Function` or the constructor explicitly defines `this.protoytpe = ...;`. It won't exist otherwise as `prototype`s are properties of the `constructor`s, not of the instance.

Comment: The first isn't really a problem.  The 2nd can be fixed by checking the value of this.constructor.prototype.method before setting it.

Answer (score 4):

this.prototype would refer to that instance of the class object.  It wouldn't give you much benefit because of the scope.

Class.prototype is adding functionality to the Class, not the instance of it.

Answer (score 3):

`Class` is a function; `this` is an object. Functions have a `prototype` property; objects do not. There's a `__proto__` property defined on objects, but that interface is deprecated. You can do something like

```
function Class () {
    var prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    prototype.method = function () {};
}
```

inside your constructor but it's not really good practice - every time `Class` is instantiated, it will needlessly waste cycles overwriting `method` on the prototype, and in cases with more complex code, may end up wasting memory as well.

In short, there's no upside and possibly serious downsides to doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same effect in two different ways. But in both, you must first instantiate Class.

First way

```
function Class () {
    var prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    prototype.foo=100
}

new Class()

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Class.prototype))
```

And second

```
function Class () {
    //var prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    var prototype=this.constructor.prototype
    prototype.foo=100
}

new Class()

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Class.prototype))
```

Both give output

```
["constructor", "foo"]
```

The only difference is that instead of doing `this.constructor.prototype` you can get it returned from `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)`. Both returns the prototype of an instance of Class.